# Calculating an area of a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling

```
close all, clear *, clc

% load('dataset1.mat');
% plot(x,y, '-'), hold on

load('dataset2.mat');
plot(x,y, '-'), hold on

fi=y;
n=length(x);

result = 0;

for j =1:n
I=simpsons(fi,x(1),x(n),[]);
result=result+I;
end

o = 1;
disp('Ergebnis:' + o); % had before this: disp('Ergebnis:' + result); 
                    % but also that didnt work and I got these weird
                    % numbers
```

with the simpson method I wanted to calculate the area of this graph but it doesn't work I get wird numbers in my command window

[image]

```
function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
n=numel(f)-1; 
h=(b-a)/n;
I= h/3*(f(1)+2*sum(f(3:2:end-2))+4*sum(f(2:2:end))+f(end));
end
```

Comment: What is `simpsons`? It does not seem to be any build in matlab function.

Comment: Other than the above comment, what is the purpose of  the loop? since you're not using the loop variable `j` anywhere inside the loop. If you just want to add the results, why not simply multiply it with `n` instead of the loop? Finally what `disp('Ergebnis:' + result);` will display is dependent on the ascii value of the letters. You probably want to do this instead : `disp(['Ergebnis: ' , num2str(result)])`

Comment: okay I got that now i just used disp(result) which gives me the result of 0 so my simpsons method for the integration of this dataset doesnt work what I am doing wrong? I updated my initial post by adding my simpsons method